# When should I use *for* before an object on the verb *pay*?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I thought *pay* is used in the form of *pay X (person) for A (object)*. But I have also found the two sentences:

- He is paying his invoice.
- He has three loans to pay for his house.

So how can I know if I should use a proposition *for* before the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "for" to describe why someone is paying.

> Pay Bob for the sandwiches.

You bought sandwiches, and that's the "why."

> He is paying his invoice.

This sentence does not have a "for." "Invoice" is a verb object, not a preposition object (what it needs for "for" to be used.) The invoice is being paid off.

> He is paying his invoice for the new door.

Now we have a preposition object (the new door) that explains why the invoice existed.

Comment: Continuing with OP's example, you would *pay the loans*, or *pay the loans for your house*. But *paying for the loans* would mean you are paying a separate, additional fee in order to obtain the loans, not pay the loan itself.

Answer (score 0):

Not too difficult...just use "for" in front of the object or service you are getting:
I pay for a meal in a restaurant.
I pay the cashier in a restaurant.

I pay my electricity bill.
I pay for my electricity.

I pay the invoice from my accountant.
I pay for my accountant to see to my tax return.

You don't need the "for" when the "pay" is followed by an infinitive:
I pay to ride into town on the bus.

but if it is a gerund, you do:
I pay for having my windows cleaned.

but that last construction is clumsy and best avoided.